# Positioning a frameset or frame

Tags: css, positioning, frame, frames, frameset

First of all: I know that it is not smart to use a `frameset` or `frame`, I know that, but this is a special case and I want to have just one simple answer: **Can I position a frame or frameset, which is now on the far left on the screen, so that I can get it on the middle of the screen?** I can move the content in the frame, but the frame itself won't move. How can I make this possible?

I tried marginwidth, but that didn't solve it.

Here is the code:

```
<frameset id=\"Q\" rows=\"75,*\" border=\"0\">
<frame name=\"haha\" src=\"home.php\" noResize scrolling=\"no\" />
<frameset cols=\"350,*\">
    <frame name=left src=\"$leftBar\">
    <frame name=main src=\"home.php?process=random\" frameborder=\"3\" noresize=\"noresize\" />
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Putting it in a div and setting the left and right margins to auto does not work?

Comment: Nope. I tried it, and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of the frame element to block and use auto left and right margins like so:

```
iframe {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/83zQX/1/

Comment: Won't work brother. It is not a IFRAME, it is a `frame`. See my first post for the code.

Comment: I honestly can't find anything on frames + CSS after a bit of googling. I am wondering if they are even supported by CSS... they aren't supported in HTML anymore...

Comment: That's too bad. Could not find anything either.... I hope someone can help me out. Thanks for your effort though.